# How do I stitch photos of and object so that I obtain a 2D picture which is basically the "unroll" of that object?

Tags: python, opencv, warp

Suppose I have an object like a Rubik cube and I take many photos around it (just the sides not the bottom or the top). I would like to make a sort of (inverse) panorama stitching of those photos to obtain a 2D image which is basically the "unroll" of the object.
It's the same as having the Earth globe, taking pictures around it and obtaining the Google Maps view we all know.

I already tried to use OpenCV (python) stitching methods but they are thought to produce panoramas. They warp images and are thought as if the viewer is inside a cylinder/sphere but in my case we are outside that's why they don't work.

EDIT:
This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anEns.png) maybe can explain better. I'm outside the cylinder on the left --> I take picture all around the cylinder --> stitch images together --> obtain the 2D map picture on the right

In my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imageio
import imutils

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive")

images = []
for i in range(1,17):
  i = str(i)
  image = cv2.imread('/content/drive/My Drive/images/rubik/'+i+'.jpg')
  images.append(image)

stitcher = cv2.Stitcher_create(1)

(status, stitched) = stitcher.stitch(images)
status


plt.figure(figsize=(18,18))
plt.imshow(stitched)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBvwZ.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say more about what isn't working. Do you see an error message? If so, what is it? It is not producing the expected output? If not, what output do you see and what output do you expect?

Comment: so you wanna project textures (from pictures) onto a cube model? you need the model and you need the texture projections before you can generate a texture map, a "net" of a cube. -- for that, you need to determine the four corners of a face in each view (just click on the pixels and record the position). from those four points, you can calculate the pose of the camera relative to the cube.